# How to reset the current axes to display either color or grayscale image on the same axes in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have some grayscale images, which after some segmentation I converted a section to color for display purposes.
But I cannot display a color image on the axes after I display a grayscale image on the same axes.

Ex:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global imB
global imF
global finalSegment_LE
i=38;
%         imB = img2{i} ;% Background original image
tempSeg = finalSegment_LE{i};
tempSeg(finalSegment_LE{i} ==0) = min(finalSegment_LE{i}(:));
imF = tempSeg;
cla(handles.axes1,'reset');
[~,~] = imoverlay(imB,imF,[],[],'hsv',0.8,handles.axes1); % color image..


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% global imB
temp = imread('cameraman.tif');
cla(handles.axes1,'reset');
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(temp,[]) % grayscale image...
```

If I press `pushbutton1` first I see a color image, but after I press `pushbutton2`, the axes become grayscale and even when I press the `pushbutton1`, It still displays a grayscale image instead of the color image.

Thanks,

Gopi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

% set colormap before displaying based on image type

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[img,cmap] = imread('peppers.png');
cla(handles.axes1,'reset');
colormap(handles.axes1,cmap);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(img,[]);


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% global imB
temp = imread('cameraman.tif');
cla(handles.axes1,'reset');
colormap(handles.axes1,gray);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(temp,[])
```